# htaccess is denying access to index.php as directory index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

order allow,deny
<FilesMatch "^(index|testfile)\.php$">
Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

Denies access to the sites root, which would typically open index.php. The only way to load the site is to go to `mysite.com/index.php` instead of `mysite.com` If I remove the `order` it works as expected, but now any files in that directory are accessible.

How do I configure the htaccess to deny all files except `index.php` but also allow for navigation to `mysite.com` instead of `mysite.com/index.php`?

Comment: Can the downvoters explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
order Deny,Allow

# deny everything except landing page
<FilesMatch ".">
Deny From All
</FilesMatch>

# allow index.php and testfile.php
<FilesMatch "^(index|testfile)\.php$">
Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

---

**Alternate Solution** using `mod_rewrite`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(?:css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico|tiff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(index|testfile)\.php). - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it looks like it still denies access unless I add a trailing `/` to the url, any way around that?

Comment: When I tested on my Apache it allows `http://localhost`, `http://localhost/index.php` and `http://localhost/testfile.php`

Comment: you can also try my alternate solution

Comment: Thanks! The rewrite rule lets me access without a trailing slash, but now I need to unblock access to all my css & js assets :/
I'll ask a followup question as that's off-topic for this one.

Comment: You can use a `RewriteCond` as I have in edited answer.